# How to find (and delete) message-less Twilio media?

Tags: node.js, twilio

If a Twilio message has been deleted, is there a way to locate any media associated with it (i.e. orphaned media)? Twilio docs explicitly state that deleting a message doesn't delete the media associated with it; if the message is gone but the media wasn't deleted first, is the media just publicly available forever?

If it's relevant, I'm using the nodejs package provided by Twilio (http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/). Overall, I'm writing an app that deletes all messages and media by looping through all messages, and then all media, using the API. If there's a better way to do that (which thus makes my question moot), please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reference now, but I believe I read somewhere that if a message is deleted, there is no longer a reference to the media instance and you're out of luck. I'm not sure if that's true.

At any rate, if I understand your question, I've had some success in the past using the  [Media portion of the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media) to list the media resources for a given message, and loop-delete the media instances first. Twilio's example of getting that list:

```
var accountSid = 'ACda6f132a3c49700934481addd5ce1659';
var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages('MM800f449d0399ed014aae2bcc0cc2f2ec').media.list(function(err, data) {
    data.medias.forEach(function(media) {
        console.log(media.ContentType);
    });
});
```

You could then go back and loop-delete messages and not risk orphaning media instances.